# SQL*Plus Query help to sum and count from different table and get the correct answer

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my query and is giving me the wrong amount. How can I fix it? It should be giving a total of 167700 but it is giving me 2515500 for the total loan. The count is working fine = 15. I can't change anything on the tables.

```
    create table loan
   (loan_number     varchar(15) not null,
    branch_name varchar(15) not null,
    amount      number not null,
    primary key(loan_number));

    create table customer
   (customer_name   varchar(15) not null,
    customer_street     varchar(12) not null,
    customer_city   varchar(15) not null,
    primary key(customer_name));


select SUM(amount),
COUNT( distinct customer_name)
from loan,customer;
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit, proper `JOIN` syntax with the conditions in the `ON` clause.  *Then you won't forget them!*

So:

```
select SUM(amount),
       COUNT( distinct customer_name)
from loan l join
     customer c
     on l.customerid = c.customerid;
```

Of course, I made up the names of the columns used for the `join`, because your question has no information describing the tables.

Comment: I know how to join a table but I dont have a common key in them. I will edit my question.

Comment: @d_PI . . . Well, loans are made to *someone*.  So, I imagine there is a table somewhere with a link between loans and customers.

Answer (score 1):

Duh! No common key in the two tables. How is that? How do you keep track of which customer took which loan?

Why are you running ONE query for data from two UNRELATED tables? The CROSS JOIN you created (by having no condition whatsoever on the enumeration of the two tables) simply joins every row from the first table to every row from the second table.

It appears the customer table has 15 rows, and all 15 names are distinct. When you COUNT DISTINCT, you get the correct number, even though in the cross join each customer_name appears many times.

On the other hand, each loan amount is repeated 15 times. 167,700 x 15 = 2,515,500.

If you need to show both the total loan amount and the number of (distinct) customers in a single row, you want something like

```
select (select sum(amount) from loan) as total_amount, 
       (select count (distinct customer_name) from customer) as distinct_customers
from   dual
;
```

Comment: There is another table that that to keep track of customer and loan.

Comment: It didn't work - maybe I had a parenthesis in the wrong space. Not everyone that comes here to ask questions is lazy and doesn't try before they ask. You should not assume. I may be bad at asking and describing the question but I know how to use google.

Comment: @d_PI - What do you mean by "it didn't work"? Did you get an error message? Did you use the query exactly as written?  For the rest, I don't know what you are referring to (with "lazy" and "google" and such) - what's that about?

Comment: Just tried you query now - it did work. Like I said "maybe I had the parenthesis in the wrong place". I had found the same example at [link](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-function.php) but I was just missing the correct order of parenthesis. - Anyway thanks and the other stuff was just me getting frustrated because I felt like you guys were assuming that I didn't know a single thing that I was talking about - but it really was just me for posting an inadequate question.